# Why represent a k-ary tree as a left-child, right-sibling tree?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I am reading the popular Intro to Algorithms book (CLRS) and it goes over creating k-ary trees using the [left child, right sibling method](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) but i am not seeing the benefit in using such a method. It states that we can use this method when k is unbounded(we dont know the number of childrens that any parents may have ahead of time). It also states that even if the number of children k is bounded by a large constant but most nodes have only few children, we may waste a lot of memory space.

To me this doesn't seem true. In C/C++/Java you create a struct or class of type Node to represent the structure of a node. Inside that struct or class you create an array of type (pointer for C/C++) Node which then lets you represent an unbounded number of children by reallocating more memory for more pointers in C/C++ or creating a new array with more space and moving the pointers(references) over in Java when needed.

If our only option was to create individual pointers/references of type Node inside our struct/class represention of node then i could see how it would be impossible to create a k-ary where k is unbounded or where k is bounded by a large constant and we end up wasting space. However we have arrays that can be dynamically resized for that purpose. Am i wrong? What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are both right and wrong. In principle, I think the book refers to the difference against reserving a fixed-size array for the children.

We do have dynamic arrays capable of growing, but they usually allocate a default-size array anyway to begin with (and later on usually double it when more space is needed), so there will still be a fraction of memory being wasted.

If you would use, say, a single linked list, you would basically be doing the same as the left-child, right sibling method.

Of course, none of these are "wrong", they just have different behaviors for updates, insertions, deletion, etc. As with any data structure.